# ScriptManager and ToolKitScriptManager in same web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax, accordion

I have on my master page this `scriptmanager`:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
```

However, i need the `ToolkitScriptManager` from `AjaxControlToolkit` to get an accordion i need on specific page to work.

```
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

So, when i execute the web project it throws me the "`You can only add one instance of ScriptManager to the page."`

How can i get rid of this situation, i just need the AjaxControlToolkit, and i really need the ScriptManager on Master page, so how can i make them work together?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you need `ScriptManager` on master page? you can have `ToolkitScriptManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `ScriptManager`  in masterpage with `ToolkitScriptManager`, you don't need content page level `ScriptManager` and also `ScriptManager` used pages will work with  `ToolkitScriptManager`

Comment: First added by writing it, said it was unknown instance, then i added it, with drag and drop procedure from AjaxToolKit tab, but now throws me same error, as if i still have scriptmanager there :(

Comment: Wait a minute, you meant, adding it to master page, then delete it from child one? Accordion menu will work without it on child page?

Comment: @KristianKoci add ToolkitScriptManager to master page and remove all other ScriptManagers and  ToolkitScriptManagers from content pages

Comment: Yes, seems to work, i mean the master code, now i have to figure out how to make the accordion work :(, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use only one script manager in master page. Either scriptmanager or toolkitscript manager both should work. Use only one scriptmanager or toolscriptmanager. I think there is no difference of using scriptmanager and toolkitscriptmanager.

Comment: I would argue that there is a difference if one works for the OP, but not the other. The accepted solution works.